# Error on update EDMX file

Tags: .net, entity-framework, exception

I create a connection with MySQL using asp.net edmx file but show error on update. In my project a ssdl file is also included. i don't know how to update ssdl file but update the edmx file and it is updated successfully and also verified mapping. My new table is mapped successful but it shows the following error on runtime:

> Error 3027: No mapping specified for the following EntitySet/AssociationSet - DiscoveredDevices, Images, Logs, Subnets, Users, Roles, ImageDeployments, OSTypes, ImageDeplymentProgressInfoes, ProcessorLoadPercentages, MemoryStatus, HDDStatus1, ActiveClients, PasswordRecoveryEmailSettings, Settings, DeploymentLoginCredentials.

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: edmx is Entity Framework file, no relation with ASP.NET MVC

Comment: but it is used for database connection in MVC

Answer (score 0):

You have entities in your model that are no longer in your DB tables or vice versa. You need to manually update your model to fix this. This often occurs if you update your Database tables (renaming or deleting columns/tables) and then just click `update model from Database`

You will find more information in the `Mapping Details` of each entity.

Comment: I did right click on my table and click on update mapping but it doesn't show all table to map it shows only newly added table how i can reslove my issue

Comment: @riwan Post modified. If you just need the model without much changes you can also just drop your current and let the EF create a new one. And after that you really should read a book about the EF!

Comment: I drop my current edmx file and add new one but it doesn't work